# How to loop inside a hash?

Tags: ruby, hash

If I have a hash like the one below, and I want to loop over the second level keys.

Why does this fail?

```
hash["Element"].each do |id|
  h[id] = hash[id]["Name"]
end
```

hash

```
{
    "Element" => {
        "499723" => {
                      "Name" => "A",
         },
        "499725" => {
                      "Name" => "B",
     },
}
```

Comment: You're getting down votes on your question because this could have been figured out by reading [the documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Hash.html#method-i-each) for Hash's `each`. “[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/128421)” will help explain why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It fails because using `.each` on a Hash yields the tuple of key and value.

```
hash = {
  "Element" => {
    "499723" => {
      "Name" => "A",
     },
    "499725" => {
      "Name" => "B",
     },
  }
}

hash["Element"].each do |id|
  p id
end

["499723", {"Name"=>"A"}]
["499725", {"Name"=>"B"}]
```

Therefore, you need to use

```
hash["Element"].each do |id, value|
  # ...
end
```

If you don't need the value

```
hash["Element"].each do |id, _|
  # ...
end
```

However, you can keep the value and access it directly

```
hash["Element"].each do |id, value|
  h[id] = value["Name"]
end
```

A simple solution in your case is to use [`Enumberable#each_with_object`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_object) in combination with the previous information:

```
hash["Element"].each_with_object({}) do |(id, value), acc|
  acc[id] = value["Name"]
end

# => {"499723"=>"A", "499725"=>"B"}
```

Comment: When would I want to use the last example you gave compared to the second last, which requires less typing?

Comment: In you original example you used an accumulator `h` to store the returned value. You didn't include it in your question. The last version I proposed doesn't require an extra variable as accumulator. The amount of "typing" is not always a measure of good code.

Comment: Very nice! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
hash["Element"].each.with_object({}) do |(id, subhash), result|
  result[id] = subhash["Name"]
end
```